# change activity theme inside the fragment without recreating it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

I have an activity which has some fragments and fragments are replaced with each other in activity when some special events happen. when I change the activity's theme, it will be recreated and it will add the first fragment and I will loose the back stack, the problem is that
I want to know that is there any way to start activity and attach the last fragment to it? or can I send back stack Fragments to the recreated activity? 
Thanks.